# Android ndk-build fails with dyld error

Tags: android, compilation, native, dyld

I'm doing the following tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/.

And I can't seem to compile properly.  I get the following error:

```
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
Compile thumb  : ndk1 <= native.c
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/ndk1/native.o] Trace/BPT trap
```

I'm running Mac OS X 10.5.8.  I'm using Gnu Make 3.81.  I'm using the awk that ships with mac os x.  And I'm using android ndk r7b.

The dyld error seems to pop up with a lot of code compiled for 10.6 and then tried on a 10.5.8 machine.

Android.mk make file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE := ndk1
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

native.c file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define DEBUG_TAG "NDK_NDKtestActivity"

void Java_my_mumbo_jumbo_NDKtestActivity_helloLog(JNIEnv * env, jobject this, j\
string logThis)
{
  jboolean isCopy;
  const char * szLogThis = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, logThis, &isCopy);
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:LC: [%s]", szLogThis);
  (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, logThis, szLogThis);
}
```

Am I not including an android library in my path possibly?  I've only added the android r7b folder to my path so i could find ndk-build?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

```
Please look at this links.it may be helpfull..
http://psrdotcom.blogspot.in/2011/12/android-ndk-jni-windows-xp7-with-3264.html#!http://psrdotcom.blogspot.com/2011/12/android-ndk-jni-windows-xp7-with-3264.html
http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade to NDK 6b as shown here:
https://ar.qualcomm.at/arforums/showthread.php?t=1590

Vaclav